# How Do I ONLY Erase The Draw Path Not The Image On The Canvas On Android?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm making an drawing application on android, that are able to load image to the canvas and draw on it, but i don't know how to erase only the drawpath, right now if i were to erase the drawpath it will also delete the image that i put on the canvas, is there a way to only erase the drawpath ?

Here Is My Code:

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

    private Path drawPath;
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap,image=null;

    private Rect clipBounds;
    private Rect destImageRect;

    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f,pivotPointX = 0.f,pivotPointY=0.f,offSetX=1.00f,offSetY=1.00f;
    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
    private boolean isGesture = false;
    private boolean brushScalling = true,erase = false;

    private ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
    private GestureDetector GD;




    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

        SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(context,new ScaleGestureListener());
        GD = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

        setupDrawing();
    }

    protected void setupDrawing(){
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();

        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;

        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        destImageRect = new Rect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    }

    public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
        float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        brushSize = pixelAmount;
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    }

    public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
        lastBrushSize = lastSize;
    }

    public float getLastBrushSize(){
        return lastBrushSize;
    }

    public void setErase(boolean isErase){
        erase = isErase;

        if(erase) {
            drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        }else{
            drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
        }
    }

    public void changeBackground(Bitmap bitmap){
        //store image to local var
        image = bitmap;
        //get offset of resolution between image and canvas
        offSetY = (float)image.getHeight()/getHeight();
        offSetX = (float)image.getWidth()/getWidth();
        //creating new canvas
        canvasBitmap = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        //when size changed, store the new size
        destImageRect = new Rect(0,0,w,h);
        //check whether to use image as background or not
        if(image == null) {
            canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
        }else{
            canvasBitmap = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
        clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,null, destImageRect,canvasPaint);
        canvas.restore();


    }


    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            //zoom out with zoom point of (0,0) top,left
            mScaleFactor=1.f;
            pivotPointX=pivotPointY=0;

            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            //need two finger to be on the screen to be register as scrolling
            if(e1.getPointerCount()==2 || e2.getPointerCount()==2){
                pivotPointX += distanceX / mScaleFactor;
                pivotPointY += distanceY / mScaleFactor;
            }

            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }
    }


    public class ScaleGestureListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            //get the zoom point or center point of the zoom
            pivotPointX = (detector.getFocusX()/mScaleFactor)+clipBounds.left;
            pivotPointY = (detector.getFocusY()/mScaleFactor)+clipBounds.top;

            return super.onScaleBegin(detector);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            //get scale factor
            mScaleFactor*=detector.getScaleFactor();
            //set the limit of zoom
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 20.0f));

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            super.onScaleEnd(detector);

            drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize/mScaleFactor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float touchX = (event.getX()*offSetX/mScaleFactor) + clipBounds.left;
        float touchY = (event.getY()*offSetY/mScaleFactor) + clipBounds.top  ;
        //pass the motion event to the gesture detector first
        SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
        GD.onTouchEvent(event);
        //preventing the used of two finger to trigger drawing event
        if(event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (!isGesture) {
                        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (!isGesture) {
                        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    isGesture = false;
                    drawPath.reset();
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }else if(event.getPointerCount() > 1){
            //if two finger are registered at the screen then it is flag as gesture
            //until no finger are on the screen
            isGesture = true;
        }
        //trigger the onDraw() function
        invalidate();

        return true;

    }

    public void setColor(String newColor){
        invalidate();
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I apply undo functionality with the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `onDraw` code to draw in two phases.

First, you draw the image.  Since it's being drawn separately, you won't put the image in your canvas bitmap.

Then you draw the canvas bitmap with your path rendered.  The ARGB8888 bitmap should be transparent to start, so doing it this way shouldn't look any different.

```
    public void changeBackground(Bitmap bitmap){
        //store image to local var
        image = bitmap;
        //get offset of resolution between image and canvas
        offSetY = (float)image.getHeight()/getHeight();
        offSetX = (float)image.getWidth()/getWidth();
        //creating new canvas
        // DON'T COPY IMAGE canvasBitmap = image.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        // just make a blank bitmap
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        //when size changed, store the new size
        destImageRect = new Rect(0,0,w,h);

        // DON'T COPY IMAGE - just make a blank bitmap
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, pivotPointX, pivotPointY);
        clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
        if (image != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        }
        // first update the canvas bitmap
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        // then draw it on top of the image
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap,null, destImageRect,canvasPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Comment: It Work, Thanks @KrisLarson

Comment: How do I apply undo functionality with the same code?

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan Undo is going to require a lot more code as the `Path` here contains everything the user has drawn; there is no "undo" method on `Path`.  You would have to put each of the user's drawing gestures into a `Stack`, then drawing entails looping over the stack and rendering each entry.  An "undo" would just be popping the stack.  If you need more help, please post a new question along with your code for the community to answer.

Comment: @krislarson Thank you very much... I'm posting a new question. Please help me out there.

Comment: @krislarson here is my question. Please help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60051267/how-do-i-undo-using-path-on-a-canvas